# How to force Mathematica to output a function using its alternate pretty form when using Apply?

Tags: functions, evaluation, output-formatting, hold, output

By default, `Bra` is an undefined function.
Let's say I have defined `Bra`,

```
Bra[a___]:=...
```

such that running `Bra[0,1]` outputs

```
{{0,1,0,0}}
```

This is essentially the notation used when dealing with qubits in quantum computing.

---

### The problem

I have a list `L={0,1}`. I want to define a function `f` such that `f[L]` outputs the unevaluated `Bra[0,1]` in its pretty form in the console.

```
f[b_List] := Defer[Apply[Bra, b]]
```

However, running `f[L]` instead outputs:

```
Bra @@ {0, 1}
```

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to output like this instead? (while maintaining `StandardForm`)
[image]

Comment: You could do `f[{b__}] := Defer[Bra[b]]`, although I don't know why you would want to do this.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked as desired. I didn't think of that.

Comment: It is a part of a larger function that I am writing. Its purpose is to take an input matrix, and outputs in terms of deferred ```Bra```s and ```Ket```s.
I am writing all these to make my life easier doing calculations involving Kets and Bras in my Quantum Information course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was given by **Carl Woll**:

```
f[{b__}] := Defer[Bra[b]]
```

Thank you!